# How to correctly save in controller function into two separate tables

Tags: laravel, vue.js, element-ui

I'm trying to save an item I created which has options that belong to it, in my case it's a question that has options like the answer options. The question is saved into it's own table, and the options are in a separate table.

This is the table structure

```
Schema::create('survey_questions', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('question');
    $table->integer('survey_section_id')->unsigned();
    $table->integer('response_type_id')->unsigned();
    $table->boolean('optional');
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->foreign('survey_section_id')->references('id')->on('survey_sections');
    $table->foreign('response_type_id')->references('id')->on('response_types');
});

Schema::create('survey_question_options', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('survey_question_id')->unsigned();
    $table->string('option');
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->foreign('survey_question_id')->references('id')->on('survey_questions');
});
```

The relationships go like this

SurveyQuestion Model

```
public function surveyQuestionOption()
{
    return $this->hasMany(SurveyQuestionOption::class);
}
```

SurveyQuestionOption Model

```
public function surveyQuestion()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(SurveyQuestion::class);
}
```

This is my current store method in the controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    DB::beginTransaction();
    $preg = new SurveyQuestion;
    $preg->question = $request->question;
    $preg->survey_section_id = $request->survey_section_id;
    $preg->response_type_id = $request->response_type_id;
    $preg->optional = $request->optional;
    $preg->save();

    if ($request->has('questionOptions')) {
        $questionOptions = [];
        $survey_question_id = $preg->id;

        foreach ($request->get('questionOptions') as $item) {
            $option = $item['option'];

            if (isset($option)) {
                $questionOptions[] = [
                    "survey_question_id" => $survey_question_id,
                    "option" => $option,
                ];
            }
        }
        if (count($questionOptions)) {
            SurveyQuestionOption::insert($questionOptions);
        }
    }

    $preg->save();

    DB::commit();
    return back();
}
```

This is my update

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    DB::beginTransaction();
    $preg = SurveyQuestion::findOrFail($id);
    $preg->question = $request->question;
    $preg->survey_section_id = $request->survey_section_id;
    $preg->response_type_id = $request->response_type_id;
    $preg->optional = $request->optional;
    $preg->save();

    $ids = [];
    if (!empty($request->get('questionOptions'))) {
        foreach ($request->get('questionOptions') as $item) {
            $opt = SurveyQuestionOption::where('survey_question_id', $preg->id)->first();

            if (empty($opt)) {
                $opt = new SurveyQuestionOption();
                $opt->survey_question_id = $preg->id;
            }
            $opt->option = $item['option'];
            $opt->save();
        }
    }

    if (count($ids) > 0) {
        SurveyQuestionOption::whereNotIn('id', $ids)->delete();
    }

    $preg->save();

    DB::commit();
    return back();
}
```

When I try to save on the vue it doesn't give me any errors but it also doesn't save into the survey_question_option table. I'm not entirely sure if my error is on the controller side or the vue side.